# Excel Combining Files with different schemas into one

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

My question is:
How do I combine multiple csv files where each file contains additional headings as well as the core data.

For example:

**File1**

| Candidate | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 21 |
| Bob | 25 |

**File2**

| Candidate | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | London |
| Bob | York |

**File3**

| Candidate | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 0234 |
| Bob | 0128 |

**Desired Combined File**

| Candidate | ID | Age | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 0234 | 21 | London |
| Bob | 0128 | 25 | York |

When I import from folder into Excel, in PowerQuery editor this hits a wall due to the schemas being different. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

You have to import these 3 files separately and afterwards merge them on the *Candidate* column. You can't use "Get data from folder", since the file structures are different.

[image]

The M-code is pretty straight forward:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(
        #"File 1", {"Candidate"}, 
        #"File 2", {"Candidate"}, 
        "File 2", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(
        Source, {"Candidate"}, 
        #"File 3", {"Candidate"}, 
        "File 3", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded File 2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Merged Queries", 
        "File 2", {"Location"}, {"Location"}),
    #"Expanded File 3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Expanded File 2", "File 3", {"ID"}, {"ID"})
in
    #"Expanded File 3"
```

Comment: So there’s no way to create in a way that all I’d have to do is refresh once? 

Or could I ‘get data from folder’ where each report is in individual folders and they get pulled in that way? The data updates every day, so trying to automate as much as possible

Comment: I don't see the problem because you only need to update once anyway. How many different files/headers do you have, I mean it should be a finite number so you don't need to keep this variable?

Comment: Hmm okay - sorry I think I'm a bit lost. When you say 'merge' them onto the candidate column, what do I do in Excel to achieve this? Have you got any documentation to help

Comment: No, but Microsoft has: [Merge queries (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to do this.

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReference()
'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20151214
    Dim xSht  As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo, "Kutools for Excel") = vbYes Then xSht.UsedRange.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.txt")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        xWb.Close False
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files csv", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub


Sub MoveData()

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range([A1], Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

On Error Resume Next
With Rng
.AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:="Book1"
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]